# Unable to import classes from aar

Tags: android

I have created an AAR using the steps suggested in the [android official documentaion](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#CreateLibrary).

In another project I import the AAR using the steps suggested in the same documentation. It basically creates a new directory with the .aar file and a build.gradle file.

But I am unable to import any classes from the AAR.

Say the package name of the AAR is com.example.example, I am only for prompted for `R` when i try to do an import.

`import com.example.example`

Any help?